# Firebird ODBC connection (64-bit) fails with 'username and password are not defined'

Tags: odbc, 64-bit, firebird

I've installed Firebird 3.0.3 Classic Server 32-bit on a newly setup Windows Server 2016 (32-bit because I have to use a legacy UDF dll that's only available in 32-bit). Except for the 64-bit ODBC connection, all connections work fine from client machines (32-bit ODBC connection, FlameRobin). But when I try to access the database through the 64-bit ODBC DSN, I get the error "your username and password are not defined".

My client machine in this case is a Windows Server 2012 R2. I've done the following steps:

1. install the 32-bit Firebird Client libraries (version 3.0.3)
2. install the 64-bit Firebird Client libraries (version 3.0.3)
3. install the 32-bit ODBC driver (version 2.0.5.156)
4. install the 64-bit ODBC driver (version 2.0.5.156)
5. open the 32-bit Windows ODBC administration console and create the DSN - connection test OK
   Screenshot: https://postimg.cc/WDrJQryH
6. open the 64-bit Windows ODBC administration console and create the DSN - connection error! 
   Screenshot: https://postimg.cc/5XDC7psz

I'm sure I haven't missspelled the password. What could I have missed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check the location of the `fbclient.dll` for both 32 bit and 64 bit (probably 64 bit in C:\Windows\System32 and 32 bit in C:\Windows\SysWoW64), and check if there is a `firebird.conf` present in that location, and if so what the config value for `AuthClient` is.

Comment: in ODBC64 setup try to specify "client" field into something like "c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0\bin\fbclient.dll" // also try to run SysInternals Process Monitor and record two those files I/O tracks: when u press "test connection" butotns in ODBC32 and ODBC64 windows. Compare the logs - where they would start badly diverting is probably where things go badly different

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I found out that the 64-bit `fbclient.dll` was not in the C:\Windows\System32 directory. I copied it there. There was no `firebird.conf` present anywhere on the client machine.

Comment: @Arioch'The , specifying the "client" field with the fbclient.dll in the "program files" folder worked! Great! Would you please add this as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted one, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general problems like this (when you have two almost identical applications and only one of them working) are often diagnosed by comparing their behavior and looking for differences, then trying to change computer or application setting to eliminate suspicious and unneeded differences unless both program work. A useful tool for it would be for example SysInternals Process Monitor, which can be set to record files I/O tracks (also registry and other things), which can give a valuable insight into program implementation and its failure. In this particular case when u press "test connection" buttons in ODBC32 and ODBC64 windows the track of files and registry accesses would probably highlight where things start go wrong for 64-bits application in contrast with the 32-bits one.

If to skip systematic diagnostic for a while and try mere guessing, then Mark suggests that the 64-bit app fails to locate the proper `fbclient.dll` (where proper might mean many things: FB version, 32/64-bitness, textual configuration files and what not).

Seeing your ODBC setup windows have an explicit fields "Client" with "Browse" button I make a guesstimation that ODBC tries to auto-locate the client library and for some reason locates some unlucky one. 
Then I suggest you to try to set that "Client" field to precisely the `fbclient.dll` file that the Firebird engine itself uses, and if you did not changed default installation settings it would be something like something like "c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0\bin\fbclient.dll"